# Error when installing python-xbrl 1.0.7

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, xbrl

I got the problem of installing xbrl module to python, and it has bothered me for two days and I haven't solved it. I successfully installed pip. I got the same problem when installing lxml

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-xbrl/1.0.7

When I use: $sudo pip install python-xbrl, I got

```
Downloading/unpacking python-xbrl
  Downloading python-xbrl-1.0.7.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/python-xbrl/setup.py) egg_info for package python-xbrl

Installing collected packages: python-xbrl
  Running setup.py install for python-xbrl
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/xbrl.py from 644 to 755

    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/xbrl.py to 755
Successfully installed python-xbrl
Cleaning up...
```

I assume that it is installed successfully, however, when I import xbrl, it doesn't work

```
$python

>>> import xbrl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xbrl
```

I also tried to install lxml using pip, but I always got something wrong when cleaning up:

```
    ...
copying vvv/bzrlib/README.txt -> build/lib/vvv/bzrlib

running install_lib

creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ghettoci

error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ghettoci': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/vvv/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip-sGfgXW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/kn/mmhj7w0n54s4b2jr08sx46kr0000gn/T/pip_build_youweizhu/vvv
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/youweizhu/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I got the same problem all the time when installing most of the modules. I'm desperate after 30 hours' try. So please help me. Thanks!

Comment: That's because the package is broken: https://github.com/greedo/python-xbrl/issues/12